# Formula for Daily Cash Balance Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-query, google-forms

I have created a Google Form for cashiers to balance out their cash drawers at the end of each day. Currently I have the form set so that they only have to count the amount of each coin/bill and not the $ amount. Their answers are logged on a spreadsheet.

I would love to create a formula that computes the $ amount and totals it up. Problem is, when I try to do this my formula is too long for what google allows. Is there a better formula for this type of computing. Formula I am trying to use is: sum(e5*.01,e6*.05,e7*.10,e8*.25,e9*1,e10*5,e11*10,e12*20,e13*50,e14*100)
As you can see, once I get to e9 the formula is distorted and no longer registers the multiplication.

I have also tried totaling up each row into cells on a separate sheet, then doing sum formula of those cells, but ideally this is something I need to reproduce 365 times and am looking for a less time consuming method.

Comment: Please share a link to a copy of the spreadsheet, keeping in mind that we cannot see what you are seeing. This will be the only way for the volunteer contributors here to assess what is happening and suggest a solution. On the surface, what you are describing is not typical and may be due to an entry error that is trying to read `e` as the exponential math function; but there is no way to know without seeing it in context. The formula as shown in your post also doesn't make sense for row-by-row form processing, since it appears to be attempting to process a single *column*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your formula is missing the multiplication operator (`*`) for the dollar bills.

The correct formula is:

`=sum(E5*0.01,E6*0.05,E7*0.1,E8*0.25,E9,E10*5,E11*10,E12*20,E13*50,E14*100)`

---

**Sample**

[image: snapshot]

Comment: That's what I was trying to do and the formula kept leaving out the * once I got to the $1 part like my example. For whatever reason, when I copied and pasted your formula it worked. I have no idea why it won't let me do it, but I appreciate your help.

Comment: Such is life, eh. If this answer was good, then you might consider [accepting](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) it.